# image rotating to right after snapshot is taken - UPDATED WIth Snapshots

Tags: ios

In my app, I need to crop an image, and then extract text from it. For this, I am using OCR. Everything works fine, but on iPad 2, when I take the picture from too close, the picture automatically rotates to the right or left after I snap the photo.

Note that my app supports only portrait mode, not Landscape.

Also, I have created an overlay for cropping, which is very small rectangular box on top of the camera screen. However, when I rotate the iPad in landscape, the imagepicker controls move with it. How can I stop it???

This is how i want it

[image]

This happens when i take the picture from too close

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutoRotateInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orintation{
    if(orintation==UIIntefaceOrientationPortait)
   {
     captureLayer.connection.videoOrientation=AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
   }
   return (orintation==UIIntefaceOrientationPortait);
}
```

Comment: i.e should be the instance of AVCaptureVideoOrientation